# Browserify adding unwanted directories

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

Setting up gulp for the first time. I've got it correctly compiling the files, it's just sticking them in the wrong place, and I can't quite figure out what to change to get it right.

After they compile, I have it adding the .conveyor.js suffix and then I want it to place them in the /scripts directory. But it's placing them in /scripts/src/js/ — it's adding a couple subdirectories. The raw dev files themselves are in src/js/ directories in a separate location, but I don't want that to carry over. Here's my gulp setup:

```
module.exports = function() {
    var files = [
        './src/js/dashboard.js',
        './src/js/pages.js',
        './src/js/poll.js'
    ];

    var tasks = files.map(function(entry) {
        return browserify({ 
            entries: [entry],
            paths: ['./node_modules', './src/js/']
        })
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source(entry))
        .pipe(rename({
            extname: '.conveyor.js'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../scripts/')); 
    });

    return es.merge.apply(null, tasks);
};
```

The way I understand it, "files" are all of the files it looks for to compile. "paths" allow you to specify directories that your require statements can be relative to so you don't have to do a bunch of period-forwardslashing. and then "dest" is where you want the files to end up. But I'm clearly misunderstanding something.

Comment: Do you need three separate bundled files, or just one?

Comment: Yes, I need them separate. They are for different pages. But they share a few of the same modules.

Comment: Gotcha. So used to the SPA and not separating.  I think I know the issue.

Comment: You ever get this to work?

Comment: Not this specific approach. I abandoned it and just split each page up into separate tasks. It's more setup work upfront (especially when you just want to add a page). But it makes the dev builds much faster when you're doing just one page at a time. Then I have one macro-task that runs all of the separate page builds. Still wish it could be a bit more automated, but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

The offender is here

```
.pipe(source(entry))
```

`entry` is set to the *exact* path you are using for the files path. Hence the duplication.

`source()` in this isn't the source of the file, but ends up being the file that gets created.

You would want to modify the object to provide just the file name as the `entry` and the source path is separated. Also, you can drop the `rename` method, I think.